# Get same date in different timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, localdate, zoneddatetime

I have a epochmilli sec time.
Created a date object from this epoch time.

`Date date = new Date(epochMilli);`

Suppose date is `"23 Nov 2019 00:00:00"`

Now, I just want to get this same date in different timezones like :]

Japan time : 23 Nov 2019 00:00:00

US time : 23 Nov 2019 00:00:00

I am currently using `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

But when I am converting into different zone, time also changes. But I don't want this time to change.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show us the value of `epochMilli` you have used?

Comment: The time should change from zone to zone, what you are searching is not possible

Comment: epockMilli value : 1574208000000L

Comment: What do you actually want - the same point in time (time in millis stays the same), but rendered for different time zones (wall-clock time varies)? Or do you want the same wall-clock time for different time zones (time in millis varies)?

Comment: @JochenReinhardt I *guess* OP wants `ZonedDateTime`s of the date `"23 Nov 2019 00:00:00"` in different time zones, that means he wants different instants that all show the same date and time. But we cannot be sure about this...

Comment: Got the solution. 
```Long epochMilli = 1574208000000L;```

```LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli),
                ZoneId.of("UTC");```

```ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));```

This zonedDateTime will return 20 Nov 2019 in Japan time.

Sorry If I am not clear before.

Comment: Just convert to `LocalDate`. It's a date without time of day and without time zone, so I figure it should give you what youvwant independently of time zone. And I recommend you stay far away from the `Date` class that you are also using in the question. It's poorly designed and lobg outdated, and you have no use for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't show us *how* you used `ZonedDateTime`, so the following examples may cover more than you just wanted by showing how to parse millis, convert the resulting date time from one zone to others and how to parse a date time using different zones:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long epochMillis = 1574208000000L;
    
    // define a formatter to be used
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                                        Locale.ENGLISH);

    // create an instant from the milliseconds
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis);
    // and create some example time zones for later use
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    ZoneId tokyo = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo");
    ZoneId losAngeles = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    ZoneId chicago = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
    
    /*
     * Part 1: Getting the date time converted to different time zones
     */
    
    // use the instant to create a ZonedDateTime at a specific time zone, here: UTC
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = instant.atZone(utc);

    // then take the UTC-ZonedDateTime as base for conversion to other time zones 
    ZonedDateTime asiaTokyoConvertedfromUtc = utcZdt.withZoneSameInstant(tokyo);
    ZonedDateTime americaLosAngelesConvertedfromUtc = utcZdt.withZoneSameInstant(losAngeles);
    ZonedDateTime americaChicagoConvertedfromUtc = utcZdt.withZoneSameInstant(chicago);

    // print the results
    System.out.println("#### 1574208000000L at UTC, converted to other zones ####");
    System.out.println("UTC time zone:\t\t\t\t" + utcZdt.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("JST (Japan/Tokyo) time zone:\t\t"
                        + asiaTokyoConvertedfromUtc.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("PST (USA/Los Angeles) time zone:\t"
                        + americaLosAngelesConvertedfromUtc.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("CST (USA/Chicago) time zone:\t\t"
                        + americaChicagoConvertedfromUtc.format(dtf));
    
    System.out.println();

    /*
     * Part 2: Getting the date time in different time zones
     */
    
    // use the instant to create a ZonedDateTime at Asia/Tokyo
    ZonedDateTime asiaTokyoFromMillis = instant.atZone(tokyo);

    // use the instant to create a ZonedDateTime at America/Los Angeles
    ZonedDateTime americaLosAngelesFromMillis = instant.atZone(losAngeles);

    // use the instant to create a ZonedDateTime at America/Chicago
    ZonedDateTime americaChicagoFromMillis = instant.atZone(chicago);

    // print the (expected) results, same as converted date times...
    System.out.println("#### 1574208000000L at different zones ####");
    System.out.println("UTC time zone:\t\t\t\t" + utcZdt.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("JST (Asia/Tokyo) time zone:\t\t"
                        + asiaTokyoFromMillis.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("PST (USA/Los Angeles) time zone:\t"
                        + americaLosAngelesFromMillis.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("CST (USA/Chicago) time zone:\t\t"
                        + americaChicagoFromMillis.format(dtf));
    
    System.out.println();
    
    /*
     * Part 3: How to parse the date time instead of millis
     */
    
    // provide a parseable date time String
    String dateTime = "23 Nov 2019 00:00:00";
    
    // parse it in each desired time zone
    ZonedDateTime utc23Nov2019 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, dtf).atZone(utc);
    ZonedDateTime asiaTokyo23Nov2019 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, dtf)
                                                    .atZone(tokyo);
    ZonedDateTime americaChicago23Nov2019 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, dtf)
                                                         .atZone(losAngeles);
    ZonedDateTime americaLosAngeles23Nov2019 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, dtf)
                                                            .atZone(chicago);

    // print the results, now you have the 23. Nov 2019 at 00:00:00 at each time zone
    System.out.println("#### \"23 Nov 2019 00:00:00\" at different zones ####");
    System.out.println("UTC time zone:\t\t\t\t" + utc23Nov2019.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("JST (Asia/Tokyo) time zone:\t\t"
                        + asiaTokyo23Nov2019.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("PST (USA/Los Angeles) time zone:\t"
                        + americaChicago23Nov2019.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("CST (USA/Chicago) time zone:\t\t"
                        + americaLosAngeles23Nov2019.format(dtf));
}
```

The output of this is

```
#### 1574208000000L at UTC, converted to other zones ####
UTC time zone:                      20 Nov 2019 00:00:00
JST (Japan/Tokyo) time zone:        20 Nov 2019 09:00:00
PST (USA/Los Angeles) time zone:    19 Nov 2019 16:00:00
CST (USA/Chicago) time zone:        19 Nov 2019 18:00:00

#### 1574208000000L at different zones ####
UTC time zone:                      20 Nov 2019 00:00:00
JST (Asia/Tokyo) time zone:         20 Nov 2019 09:00:00
PST (USA/Los Angeles) time zone:    19 Nov 2019 16:00:00
CST (USA/Chicago) time zone:        19 Nov 2019 18:00:00

#### "23 Nov 2019 00:00:00" at different zones ####
UTC time zone:                      23 Nov 2019 00:00:00
JST (Asia/Tokyo) time zone:         23 Nov 2019 00:00:00
PST (USA/Los Angeles) time zone:    23 Nov 2019 00:00:00
CST (USA/Chicago) time zone:        23 Nov 2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: Great effort! You can make it simpler this way: `Instant utcFromMillis = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis); ZonedDateTime asiaTokyoConvertedfromUtc = utcFromMillis.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));`.

Comment: I just had a quick glance and found that there is still one more thing to change. It is better to change `ZonedDateTime asiaTokyoConvertedfromUtc = utcZdt.toInstant().atZone(tokyo);` to `ZonedDateTime asiaTokyoConvertedfromUtc = instant.atZone(tokyo);` as I had suggested in my first comment. You can even change `ZonedDateTime utcZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, utc);` to `ZonedDateTime utcZdt = instant.atZone(utc);` to make it consistent with next three statements (once you have updated them as I have suggested).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks again, I considered the two suggestions in my last edit.

Comment: After going through it, I felt that only two parts are required for this demonstration. I have rewritten this program [here](https://ideone.com/XUDE46). Please compare it with your current code and feel free to use it (ultimately, our goal is to give the best possible solution and advice to the developers/learners).

Comment: Well, @ArvindKumarAvinash, you are basically right because you are an experienced developer who is used to this library. But my goal was to show different situations. In the first one there's a `long` as base, in the second a `ZonedDateTime` and in the third one a `String`. Might be too much for a single answer, but I consider those the most often situations.

Answer (score 1):

The legacy `java.util.Date` is not time-zone-aware. It is basically a point in time measured in milliseconds since 1970-1-1 0:00. Nothing else.

When a date is print, it is formatted using your system's default locale and time zone. In order to get a `java.util.Date` object formatted for a different time zone you have to configure your `DateFormat` accordingly.

```java
Date pointInTime = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(pointInTime));
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(pointInTime));
```

With the newer LocalDate API, things are different. The previous answer gives a rich example.

Comment: Not only should we not use `Date`, `DateFormat` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. We also should neither rely on nor try to parse three-letter time zone abbreviations. They are ambiguous, I think more often than not.  Use like Asia/Manilla or Pacific/Pitcairn, that is, *region/city* for time zone IDs.